# SQL JOINS AND SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**QUESTION -** Display product Id, name, and list Price for products that were purchased in orders handled by salesman Marshall and with list price greater than all average list prices per each category. Sort the output by Id ascending.

**MY Current query -**

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.list_price
FROM products p
full outer JOIN inventories i
on i.product_id = p.product_id
full outer JOIN warehouses w
on w.warehouse_id=i.warehouse_id
full outer JOIN department d
on d.location_id = w.location_id
full outer JOIN employees e
on e.manager_id = d.manager_id
WHERE UPPER(e.last_name) = 'MARSHALL';
```

**RESULTS -** null null null

**Expected results**

```
ProdId  Product Name           LPrice
     
 2      Intel something        9999.99
```

Extra info

When I use the query

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE UPPER(last_name) = 'MARSHALL';
```

I get Isabelle     Marshall

therefore I was joining all the tables but I think I should be using subquery but not sure how to approach it.

[image: 1/2 pics]
[image: 2/2 pics]

Comment: I suggest you start with "When I use the query ..." which returns desired value. Then join **only one table** to it and run the query. If you get the result, fine - add yet another table. If not, don't move further until you fix what was wrong. Do that in the loop, until you get desired result.

Comment: We can not know the reason without knowing the current data within the tables. I mean you need to share sample data from each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use full outer joins here.
Your question is about where the products were purchased in orders that were handled by a certain salesman but your query is joining from products to find which warehouses have it and then whose manager is the same manager as that warehouse - it doesn't answer the question.

I would start by joining products to the orders that involved them (guessing at the relationships between your tables):

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, p.list_price
from   products p
join   order_items oi
  on   p.product_id = oi.product_id
join   orders o
  on   oi.order_id = o.order_id
```

A row in orders has a salesman_id, my first guess would be that this links to emplyees on salesman_id = employee_id but really there could be extra conditions or you might need to use the employee table instead. It's your data so you should have a look at your own data model and test some queries to figure out how they fit together.

If we assume my guess is right, you just need to join and filter to obtain the first part of the requirement:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, p.list_price
from   products p
join   order_items oi
  on   p.product_id = oi.product_id
join   orders o
  on   oi.order_id = o.order_id
join   employees e
  on   o.salesman_id = e.employee_id
where  e.last_name = 'Marshall'
```

Next is to filter on where the list price greater than all average list prices per each category. So you could start by getting the average list prices per category:

```
select category_id, avg(list_price) avg_list_price
from   products 
group by category_id
```

You can then join that into your main query (it'll be unique on category_id) and add a filter that includes your average list price.

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, p.list_price
from   products p
join   order_items oi
  on   p.product_id = oi.product_id
join   orders o
  on   oi.order_id = o.order_id
join   employees e
  on   o.salesman_id = e.employee_id
join  (select category_id, avg(list_price) avg_list_price
       from   products 
       group by category_id
      ) c
  on   p.category_id = c.category_id
where  e.last_name = 'Marshall'
and    p.list_price > c.avg_list_price
order by p.product_id
```

I've also tacked on the order by ID ascending (assuming it refers to product_id). And we're done, assuming my guesses to your data model are correct!
(I'm also assuming it isn't really referring to the unit sales price which appears in order_items, but that should be an easy one to change if you need to).